# Which one is better? 鮮魚 or 新鮮な魚?

Tags: word-choice

I have this question about 鮮魚 or 新鮮な魚. I've read them both in different situations and I want to know if there's a correct way or in what situations can I use each of them.

Comment: 鮮魚 doesn't necessarily mean 新鮮な魚 but 生魚(なまざかな) i.e. "raw fish".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

鮮魚 is virtually a commercial term which is mostly seen in fish shops, supermarkets and sea food restaurants.
Using 鮮魚 in everyday conversation may sound slightly weird.

For example, supposing you are on a fishing boat and having a catch-and-cook lunch, if you say やっぱり鮮魚はおいしいね your friends may laugh, because it sounds a little funny. Using 新鮮な魚 is more natural in this case.